# Displaying data from database using Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, templates, variable-assignment

I am trying to get data from a database and display it using a model, controller, and view.

Here is my model

```
public function waitlist_view() {
    $data = array();
    $this->load->database();

    $this->db->select('*');
    $this->db->from('waitlist');
    $query = $this->db->get();

    return $query->row();
}
```

Here is my controller

```
public function waitlist() {
    $data['title']="parents_viewlist";
    //redirect if not logged in
    if(($this->session->userdata('logged_in')!= 1) && ($this->session->userdata('type')!='parent')) {
        redirect('login/index');
    }

    $this->load->model('parents_model');
    $data['row'] = $this->parents_model->waitlist_view();

    $this->load->view('templates/cpsheader', $data);
    $this->load->view('templates/cpsmenu');
    $this->load->view('parents/parents_viewlist', $data);
    $this->load->view('templates/cpsfooter');
}
```

Here is my view

```
<div>

    <?php echo $row->waitlist_id; ?>
    <?php echo $row->ay_code; ?>
    <?php echo $row->school_id; ?>
    <?php echo $row->waitlist_status; ?>

</div>
```

It doesnt display anything on the page when I pull it up. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: You need to do some basic debugging. In your controller `print_r($data)` to verify it has what you expect. In your view `print_r($row)` to see what it has.

Comment: Unfortunately I have done something with the php and nothing displays at all on the page

Comment: Check your logs. Turn on `error_reporting`. You probably have a PHP error somewhere and aren't displaying those in your page.

Comment: Is that something in the terminal or in the browser? I the code as php model.php and the same for the view and controller and fixed a couple errors there. Now i get an error with that, that says FATAL ERROR Class 'CI_Models' not found in /path/ in line 3;. That shows up for the model and a similar one for the controller but thats the only error I can get to show

Comment: I commented out the lines $this->load->model('parents_model');
            $data['row'] = $this->parents_model->waitlist_view(); and got the page to display again. So it looks like the php error is in these lines.

Comment: 'CI_Models' not found? make sure in your model you're extending 'CI_Model' not 'CI_Models'

Comment: This question **Needs Debugging Details**.

Answer (score 0):

in your model use result() to get data :

```
public function waitlist_view() {
$this->load->database();
 $query = $this->db->get('waitlist')->result();

return $query;
}
```

in your controller :

```
   $this->load->model('parents_model');
   $data['row'] = $this->parents_model->waitlist_view();

$this->load->view('templates/cpsheader', $data);
$this->load->view('templates/cpsmenu');
$this->load->view('parents/parents_viewlist', $data);
$this->load->view('templates/cpsfooter');
```

Now use loop on $row in your view to print data.

Comment: This is sound advice -- though I would not declare `$query`, I would just `return` the array of objects.  I would use `rows` as the key in `$data` instead of `row` to better express the data.

Answer (score -1):

In your controller print the data returned from db as:

```
echo "<pre>";print_r($data);echo "</pre>";exit;
```

add this line just after $data['row'] = $this->parents_model->waitlist_view();
Let us know what result are you getting.

Comment: Do not use "answers" to aid the OP in collecting the relevant details to complete the question.  This "answer" makes no attempt to **resolve** the error -- it is suggesting a debugging technique.